# Converting from a string to a class object in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs

So I'm am doing something that requires me to take a class (that is declared in a separate file) in this case it is a react component, and convert that to a string, remove certain things through regex to make the react component smaller, and then convert it back to a class and set that new object as a state.
If you are not familiar with react then in simple terms I need to go from class --> to string --> to class object

this is what I have so far and it returns looking like the same object but when I try to use it and set the state, it loses context or something and the var NAMESPACE comes up as being undefined.

If I try to go straight from the newState parameter and set it as the state in the function "_this.setState()" everything works as expected.

Thanks for reading I hope you can help me. FYI I am not thoroughly experienced in JS, and might be missing a major concept.

```
  setStateInChunks(newState, _this) {
     var obj = {};
     obj = newState.toString();
     var newObj = eval(obj);
    _this.setState({view: newObj});
 }
```

This is the example class object that is being set as the state

```
const React = api.React;
const ReactBootstrap = api.ReactBootstrap;

// Get Bootstrap elements
const Row = ReactBootstrap.Row;
const Col = ReactBootstrap.Col;
const Well = ReactBootstrap.Well;
const Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
const ButtonGroup = ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup;

var ExampleVar = null;

// Initialize the namespace
const NAMESPACE = 'ExampleString';

class View extends foo.Bar {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.nameSpace = NAMESPACE;

    ExampleModule = foo.bar('ExampleString');
  }
}
```

Edit: setStateInChunks() is a function that is being called in place of the standard this.setState() in my parent component. Which is used somewhat like this

`var newView = foo.getView('storedView')
    this.setStateInChunks(newView,     _this);`

Comment: "*remove certain things through regex to make the react component smaller*" - just don't do that. Keep it as an object, and remove things programmatically.

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `setStateInChunks` and what `toString()` is

Comment: @Bergi seems like it might be easier programmatically, didn't think of that. I updated my question. Thanks. This entire process is an attempt to optimize the setting of the state because it is too large and causes the program to freeze